# Who are the most important acharyas of the Gaudiya sect?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism

I want to know about most important Gaudiya Vaishnava acharyas, and also about what their major commentaries and works are.

Comment: Rupa Goswami, Sanatana Goswami, Gopalabhatta Goswami, Jiva Goswami, Raghunatha Dasa Goswami, Baladeva Vidyabhusana, Vishwanath Chakravarti, Narottama Dasa.